# Add a ref line in a column chart, but presentation is broken

Tags: python, python-pptx

So I wanted to add a ref line which value is 5, in a bar chart. like the picture:
[image: Bar Graph]
My code is like:

```
prs=Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
chart_data = ChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data.add_series('Q1 Sales', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
chart_data.add_series('Q2 Sales', (22.3, 28.6, 15.2))
chart_data.add_series('Q3 Sales', (20.4, 26.3, 14.2))

x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
cchart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
)

prs1=Presentation()
slide1 = prs1.slides.add_slide(prs1.slide_layouts[5])
chart_data1 = ChartData()
chart_data1.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data1.add_series('Q1 Sales', (5, 5, 5))
chart_data1.add_series('Q2 Sales', (5, 5, 5))
chart_data1.add_series('Q3 Sales', (5, 5, 5))

lchart = slide1.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.LINE, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data1
)
chartc = cchart.chart
chartl = lchart.chart
a=chartl.plots._plotArea
b=chartc.plots._plotArea
k=a.getchildren()[0]
b.insert(0,k)
prs.save('testbarline.pptx')
```

Problem is:
When I open the Presentation it shows "PowerPoint found a problem with content in testbarline.pptx." Then I click 'repair', it can't repair. What's the problem here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Compare the XML generated by your code against the XML for a chart you make by hand to look the way you want.

I imagine you'll find several obvious differences.

What you're trying to do is not trivial. You'll need to understand what the "target" XML is and then work from the XML produced by the `python-pptx` API to add the exact bits you need.

opc-diag is handy for this work.